# File inserting into filestream directory, but not into SQL Server 2012 table. C# ASP

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, filestream

I'm having difficulty setting up my database to accept files.  I don't fully understand what I'm doing so it will be something silly for sure.  I'll try to include as many images and as good a description as possible to identify what I've done and hopefully be able to discern what's missing or wrong.

[image]
I've enabled filestream here in the configuration manager for full access.

[image]
And on the server level here in SQL 2012 Management Studio.

[image]
And here on the database level in SQL 2012 Management Studio

[image]
This is the table I've made in that database for inserting files and later retrieving them with my asp.net app.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChangeDb"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in ReleaseNotesFile.PostedFiles) {
                    string file = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    var fileSplit = file.Split('.');
                    string filename = fileSplit[0];
                    string fileextension = fileSplit[1];
                    string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                    using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream) {
                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs)) {
                            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertFile", con)) {
                                try {
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileExtension", fileextension);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeId", 27);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileType", "ReleaseNotes");
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chart", bytes);
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                                    throw new Exception("SQL Exception on inserting ReleaseNotes file. " + sqlex.Message);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) {
                                    throw new Exception("Error inserting ReleaseNotes file. " + ex.Message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my file insert stored procedure in my c# code behind.

[image]
This is the location where the filestream is saved (ChangeGovernanceFiles)

[image]
And as we can see here, it's actually taking the files I'm submitting through my app into this directory.  However...

[image]
Nothing at all inserts into the table, despite no errors or exceptions being thrown.

I've pieced together everything I have done from quite a number of tutorials and sources to work with my existing asp.net application, and I understand very little of it.  Would someone be able to identify what I'm missing?

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Edit, adding another picture with my sql set up and stored proc that I think might further help discern what's missing.

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2  
RECONFIGURE  

alter database ChangeGovernance
add filegroup fsGroup contains filestream;
go

alter database ChangeGovernance
add file
  ( NAME = 'fsChangeGovernance', FILENAME = 'G:\ChangeGovernanceFiles'
   )
to filegroup fsGroup;
go

DROP TABLE ChangeGovernance.dbo.ChangeFiles
GO

CREATE TABLE ChangeGovernance.dbo.ChangeFiles
(
    [ChangeFileId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID(), 
    [SerialNumber] INTEGER UNIQUE,
    [Chart] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL,
    [FileName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FileExtension] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [ChangeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [FileType] NVARCHAR(50),
    [ContentType] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

--Files insert stored proc
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.InsertFile
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertFile
@Chart VARBINARY(MAX), @FileName NVARCHAR(50), @FileExtension NVARCHAR(10), @ChangeId INT, 
@FileType NVARCHAR(50), @ContentType NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeFiles (Chart, FileName, FileExtension, ChangeId, FileType, ContentType)
VALUES (@Chart, @FileName, @FileExtension, @ChangeId, @FileType, @ContentType)
END
GO
```

My setting up fileshare, the file folder, my table and my stored procedure to insert into it.

Comment: Don't use images for code or sample data. They're fine for the config screens, but for the rest it's considered very rude here to post and image instead of the code.

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry.  I'll edit that when I get back on my laptop.

Comment: I just changed the two pictures of my code to snippets.

Comment: Your stored procedure does not pass in a value for SerialNumber which does not allow nulls according to the picture of the table, but does allow nulls according to the script for the table, so which one is it? If it is a NOT NULL column as the picture indicates, the SP will fail.